# Is it possible to scope `serializeQueryArgs` alongside injected endpoints?

Tags: rtk-query

I [inject endpoints](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/code-splitting#injectendpoints) like this:

```js
export const commentsApi = generalApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getComments: builder.query<GetCommentsState, GetCommentsArgs>({
      // ...
    }),

    submitNewComment: builder.mutation<{ comment: CommentDTO }, SubmitNewCommentArgs>({
      // ...
    })
  })
})
```

and I want to use custom cache key serialization for these two endpoints.

I currently do it by providing [serializeQueryArgs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#serializequeryargs) parameter inside `generalApi` definition - but this is sub-optimal for two reasons:

1. I have to manually test if I'm calling a `commentsApi` request or not, and then import `defaultSerializeQueryArgs` and explicitely call it in cases I'm calling a different request
2. It introduces an unhealthy circular dependency flow between my modules - `commentsApi` is dependent on `generalApi`, because it injects into it, and `generalApi` is dependent on `commentsApi`, because it needs to include custom arg serializers from it.

I hate my approach, but I haven't found any other way of doing this. Do I have any better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment. If you find a way to add this with minimal overhead, a PR is very welcome.

**update**

This will be available in Redux Toolkit 1.9, which is currently in alpha preview.

Comment: Hey, I tried submitting a PR, but I cannot push into the repo: `ERROR: Permission to reduxjs/redux-toolkit.git denied to michal-kurz.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`. This is my GH: https://github.com/michal-kurz

Comment: I noticed `CONTRIBUTING.md` tells me to create an issue, so I did: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/2491